# Replace a text from the key value pairs

Tags: powershell, dictionary, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to replace a text from the key value pairs of a dictionary. Here is the powershell script I'm working on,

```
foreach ($string in $templatestrings) {


               if($Dictionary.ContainsKey($string))
                {
                    $Dictionary.Keys | % { $templatecontent = $templatecontent -replace "{{$string}}", ($Dictionary[$_]) }
                 }  

    }
 $templatecontent | set-content $destinationfilename

}
```

Basically If the text value matches with dictionary key, then we will replace the text with dictionary value. Seems the replacing part is not working as expected. I want to replace text value with dictionary value. `I'm storing the text values in $templatecontent variable.` Can someone please tell me the correct way to replace these text values.

Comment: How is this different then you last question(s) using this code where you are also asking for text replacement

Comment: @Matt
Actually in the previous question, I was matching each string with key and replacing the value. Now, I have updated the `if condition` to as follows,

`$Dictionary.ContainsKey($string)`..
Can you tell me the correct way to replace the values. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already check whether the dictionary contains your key so you can access the value to replace by using the index operator `[]`:

```
foreach ($string in $templatestrings) 
{
    if($Dictionary.ContainsKey($string))
    {
        $templatecontent = $templatecontent -replace "{{$string}}", ($Dictionary[$string])
    }  
}
```

However, you can simplify this a lot, as I showed in my last answer:

```
$templatecontent = Get-Content $sourcefilename
$Dictionary.Keys | % { $templatecontent = $templatecontent -replace "{{$_}}", ($Dictionary[$_]) } 
templatecontent | set-content $destinationfilename
```

These three lines will replace every `{{key}}`with the `value`fromt he dictionary. You don't even need the `regex` to capture the `$templatestrings`.

Comment: Yes. This is working fine. I appreciate it jisaak. Thank you so much for the solution.